# JavaFX PixelWriter/Reader get() value not == to set() value

Tags: java, javafx

Using the following code:

```
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 
public class Main {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WritableImage image = new WritableImage(1, 1);
    PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
    PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();
 
    System.out.println("Initial color: " + reader.getColor(0, 0));
 
    Color newColor = Color.web("#11111111");
    System.out.println("Setting color: " + newColor);
 
    writer.setColor(0, 0, newColor);
    System.out.println("Updated color: " + reader.getColor(0, 0));
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Initial color: 0x00000000
Setting color: 0x11111111
Updated color: 0x0f0f0f11
```

Why doesn't the Color returned equal the color set? Possibly a floating point calculation error while converting from premultiplied alpha PixelFormat and back?

Thanks @Slaw for narrowing the problem with the above example.

---

**Edit 6-7-2023:** Taking a look at this again with more details in an attempt to make the issue painfully obvious.

Screencaps are from Class "PixelUtils"...

Correct value for R (and G and B) is 17 (the original 0x11 value each color component was set to) shown here initially:

[image: Correct value for R is 17 shown here initially]

After conversion to ARGB Pre(multipled) they convert to 1:

[image: Each component set to 1]

Giving us R:1 G:1 B:1 A:17 with the components premultipled, okay fine...

Then we come to this optimized thing deep inside PixelReader.getColor() (PixelUtils.PreToNonPre()):

[image: PixelUtils.PreToNonPre()]

Starting with R=1 B=1 G=1 A=17 as calculated before, confirmed correct via debugger, this optimized (I guess) code does some math which gives us an incorrect value of 15 (0x0f) rather than the original 17 (0x11), the difference between the "Setting" and "Updated" color components documented originally.

That code comes up with 15 (0x0f) instead of 17 (0x11). Naw dawg, that's wrong:

[image: 15 instead of 17]

Notably it IS possible at least in this case to come up with the correct value using just 1,1,1,17, using more intuitive code:

[image: Nonoptimized version]

I question the value of this optimization if that's what the original method is meant to be, but more importantly now I think this rises to the level of a bug so assuming I'm at a correct conclusion, the question is:

***Is this worth attempting to get fixed in OpenJFX?*** (Or would it run into resistance to leave it as-is for some reason?)

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Note I am not a color expert. However, this does not seem to be a problem with `Color` or your math. You can test this out be creating `#11111111` colors through various means and see they'll all print out `0x11111111`. If you follow the code path of `setPixel` then you'll see it eventually does alpha premultiplication before storing the color in the internal byte buffer. And this appears to be a precision issue, though again not on your part. From what I've looked up, small alphas are the problem. For example, if you used `#111111FF` then you'd get the same color back out.

Comment: @kleopatra If you're interested, this seems to be the least amount of code needed to reproduce the problem as I understand it: https://ideone.com/mTC2eq (have to copy the code to your machine so you can include JavaFX).

Comment: Thanks @Slaw that's a perfect summary, the context I'm in had me confused about where the problem was, so a minimal example did not seem feasible. I removed all the distracting stuff and simplified the question to the core problem you narrowed it to so you can provide a real answer if you'd like. It does sound like my later edit was correct. Not sure it rises to the level of JFX bug but definitely not the behavior I'd expect.

Comment: Also, even extracting all the pixels using `PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance()` still gives you the "wrong" color. I can update the example to show that, if you want.

Comment: Thanks - if you have anything helpful you'd like to add, feel free!